Where can I define a repository function so that I can use it in my entire gradle build, including buildSrc?
I have a functions that's an alternative to mavenCentral, which creates an ArtifactRepository:
fun RepositoryHandler.myCustomRepository(): ArtifactRepository {
    // about 20 lines of code
}

I have a multi-project Gradle build that also has a buildSrc, and I want to
use myCustomRepository:

for both dependency loading and plugin loading
in my root project, all subprojects, and in buildSrc

The best I’ve found is to use settings.gradle.kts and
buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts and use the function in four places:

settings.gradle.kts in pluginManagement
settings.gradle.kts in dependencyResolutionManagement
buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts in pluginManagement
buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts in dependencyResolutionManagement

Unfortunately,
it seems that I also need to define four identical copies of the function,
two in each settings.gradle.kts file. I haven't been able to find a single place
to define it that's visible to all four locations where I need to use it.
That is:
settings.gradle.kts
fun RepositoryHandler.myCustomRepository(): ArtifactRepository {
    // copy #1
}

pluginManagement {
    fun RepositoryHandler.myCustomRepository(): ArtifactRepository {
        // copy #2
    }

    repositories {
        myCustomRepository()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        myCustomRepository()
    }
}

buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts
fun RepositoryHandler.myCustomRepository(): ArtifactRepository {
    // copy #3
}

pluginManagement {
    fun RepositoryHandler.myCustomRepository(): ArtifactRepository {
        // copy #4
    }

    repositories {
        myCustomRepository()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        myCustomRepository()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

Is there some way to define this function in only ONE place, and use it in
all four of these places?

pluginManagement is special
You cannot simply use an external function in the pluginManagement block because pluginManagement, like the plugins block, is isolated from the rest of the file1 so there is no import mechanism.
Settings plugins in a composite builds
What you can do as an alternative is to write a Settings plugin inside of an included build. Such a settings plugin can itself perform actions inside pluginManagement, including calling a given function.
Also, a settings plugin, when applied inside the plugins block, has its JAR added to classpath of the settings.gradle.kts file so you can use any other functions defined in the plugin project in that file (though not pluginManagement).
Sketch of layout
All in all that would look something like this:

An included build project which defines and exports a settings plugin using the Java Gradle plugin, and declares your function myCustomRepository(). Here's the key source file:
// myIncludedBuild/src/main/kotlin/MySettingsPlugin.kt

class MySettingsPlugin : Plugin<Settings> {
    override fun apply(target: Settings) {
        target.pluginManagement.apply {
            repositories.myCustomRepository()
        }
    }
}

fun RepositoryHandler.myCustomRepository() {
    println(this::class.qualifiedName)
}


Then in settings.gradle.kts of the main project you can do:
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("myIncludedBuild")
}

plugins {
    // Calls myCustomRepository via its apply method
    id("mySettingsPlugin")
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories.myCustomRepository()
}


buildSrc's settings.gradle.kts is identical except it needs a slightly different relative path to find the included build:
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("../myIncludedBuild")
}



Execute that build and you get the following output four times:
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler_Decorated
Use in other build.gradle.kts files
Now you have an included build, you can proceed in similar fashion with Project plugins, or directly use the buildscript blocks to add the code of the included build project to any given build.gradle.kts file.

1Gradle 6.0 upgrade instructions

I tried this, and Gradle gives an error about the plugins block in settings.gradle.kts: "Plugin [id: 'mySettingsPlugin'] was not found"

You need to set up the included build to export the plugin using the Java Gradle plugin. It is a sketch of the solution

Ah, the problem was that I hadn't correctly filled out the gradlePlugin { } block. Thanks! I wonder if it'd be possible to do this with a conventions plugin, my-settings-plugin.gradle.kts in place of MySettingsPlugin.kt. I don't know if it's possible to have Settings be the target of such a plugin, though.

Nice :) Yes, I am not aware of any way to use a script plugin in the settings file. The Gradle compiler compiles those into Plugin<Project> instances so it seems unlikely, unless there is (or will be in future) some special compilation setting.
